# Problem uploading to YouTube using Google API Java Client

Tags: java, android, google-api, youtube-api

I am using the Google API Java Client library (http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) to upload a video on my Android phone to YouTube.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
// Create the meta data
Entry entry = new Entry();
entry.group = new MediaGroup();
entry.group.title = "test title";
entry.group.description = "test description";
entry.group.category = new MediaCategory();
entry.group.category.Cat = "People\n";

XmlNamespaceDictionary namespaceDictionary = Util.NAMESPACE_DICTIONARY;

AtomContent aContent = new AtomContent();
aContent.entry = entry;
aContent.namespaceDictionary = namespaceDictionary;

// Create the actual video data
InputStreamContent bContent = new InputStreamContent();
bContent.inputStream =
    context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(media);
bContent.type = context.getContentResolver().getType(media);
bContent.length = videoAsset.getLength();

// Build up the POST request
MultipartRelatedContent multiContent = new MultipartRelatedContent();
multiContent.parts.add(aContent);
multiContent.parts.add(bContent);


HttpRequest request = transport.buildPostRequest();
request.url = YouTubeUrl.uploadUrl();
GoogleHeaders headers = (GoogleHeaders) request.headers;
headers.setSlugFromFileName("mytest.3gpp");
request.content = multiContent;
request.headers.contentType = multiContent.getType();

request.execute();
```

Unfortunately, I get an exception when calling request.execute():

```
03-06 23:28:58.887: WARN/System.err(18923): com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 415 Unsupported Media Type
03-06 23:28:58.897: WARN/System.err(18923):     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:221)
03-06 23:28:58.897: WARN/System.err(18923):     at com.abless.vidshare.YouTubeAPI.upload(YouTubeAPI.java:118)
03-06 23:28:58.897: WARN/System.err(18923):     at com.abless.vidshare.VidShare.onActivityResult(VidShare.java:185)
03-06 23:28:58.897: WARN/System.err(18923):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3931)
03-06 23:28:58.907: WARN/System.err(18923):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3730)
03-06 23:28:58.907: WARN/System.err(18923):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3776)
03-06 23:28:58.907: WARN/System.err(18923):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-06 23:28:58.907: WARN/System.err(18923):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2166)
03-06 23:28:58.907: WARN/System.err(18923):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-06 23:28:58.907: WARN/System.err(18923):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
03-06 23:28:58.907: WARN/System.err(18923):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
03-06 23:28:58.907: WARN/System.err(18923):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 23:28:58.917: WARN/System.err(18923):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-06 23:28:58.917: WARN/System.err(18923):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-06 23:28:58.917: WARN/System.err(18923):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-06 23:28:58.917: WARN/System.err(18923):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What am I doing wrong? It seems like Content-Length is not automatically specified by MultipartRelatedContent, might that be the problem? I had a look at the implementation code, and MultipartRelatedContent.getLength() returns -1, which is not very helpful.

Has anyone managed to use the Google API Java Client library to successfully upload a video to YouTube?

Thanks.

-Alexander

Edit: even if I fill out the Content-Length part, I still get the same error (415 Unsupported Media Type), so that doesn't solve it. It almost seems like the POST header is wrong?

Comment: Hey I  m also doing Same thing can u just help me out with ur suggestions ,I in trouble with these uploading videos to youtube by android application :) Please reply soon

Comment: hey anyone have done uploading youtube video in android please help me

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself...turns out the YouTubeURL used the JsonC option. After commenting out that line, everything worked beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested in an example using the new google-api-java-client, I have attached one to [bug 16](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/issues/detail?id=16).